# Use a implementation of provider inside other implementation of same provider in Angular

Tags: angular, design-patterns

I want to inject a provider implementation inside another other implementation of the same provider in Angular, but I could not achieve this.
The idea is that I can specialize the second implementation with the data from first implementation
As I read in angular documentation, is not possible use a second implementation of the same provider, but I want to know If someone has achive this in some way

Thanks

```
export abstract class Provider {
    abstract someMethod();
}

export class implProviderOne implements Provider{
    someMethod(){
    }
}

export class implProviderTwo implements Provider{
    constructor(private provider: Provider) {} // I DI injects implProviderOne in this implementation
    someMethod(){
    }
}

//This is what I try

//Main Module
//main.module.ts
@NgModule({
    ...
    imports: [InnerModule],
    providers:[
        { provide: Provider, useClass:implProviderOne}
    ], 
    ...
})
export class MainModule {}

//Inner Module
//inner.module.ts
@NgModule({
    ...
    {provide: Provider, useClass:implProviderTwo } // What I can do to achieve this?
    ...
})
export class InnerModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you want to change some provider you need to declare it.

```
    @Injectable()
    export class ProviderService {
        public someMethod(){
           console.log('My injected provider')
        }
    }
```

```
    @Injectable()
    export class ProviderTwoService {
        public someMethod(){ console.log("My swiched provider") }
    }
```

```
    @Injectable()
    export class implProviderOneService {
        constructor(private provider: ProviderService) {} // this way u inject remember it need to have scope like private, public, protected

        someFunction() {
           this.provider.someMethod() <<< this way u use injected service
         }
    }
```

```
        @NgModule({
        ...
        providers:[
             ProviderService,
            { provide: ProviderService, useClass:ProviderTwoService}
        ], 
        ...
    })
```

`{ provide: ProviderService, useClass: ProviderTwoService }` This is for change ProviderService to ProviderTwoService so wherever you were injecting and using first provider the second will be injected.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but, what i want to do is use a diferent implementation from same provider, in same scope module

This aplication show what is my problem:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-48f24k

How I can use one implementation, same provider, in a inner component in module scope from other provider without change provider signature inside components

Comment: Dude u creating AbstractProvider then change its name in file as Provider then in one files u are using Provider in other files AbstractProvider how do u want to your code works ?